# How to organize F# source of large project (>300 classes) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, assemblies, code-organization, c#-to-f#

**In C# you can put files in folders corresponding to their namespaces and view them in the Solution explorer.**

In F# it seems I have to put everything in plain specifically ordered list for compilation. When I get to scale of ~300 of classes it gets a bit confusing and disorganized and I start to envy C# and think that probably it is the price for type inference.

**Are there better options than splitting to several assemblies?**

Judging by F# compiler source its the route they have taken but I have pretty large system of interconnected components (Controller - ViewModel - View, > 300 classes) I want to be in one assembly because of circular dependencies even at level of interfaces.

**Should I forget about one file - one class and create some huge files?** (e.g. in F# compiler you have several source files in 100kb to 300kb range and some auto generated around 1Mb!)

**What is your experience with large F# projects?**

Comment: F# is trying to save you--let it! :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You mention "circular dependencies", to be clear, F# will never let you spread circular dependencies across files.  If type `Foo` refers to type `Bar` and type `Bar` refers to type `Foo`, then `Foo` and `Bar` must both be defined in the same file in the same `type ... and ...` group in F#.

The issue here is one of organization and navigation, that is mostly about the tooling.  The VS solution explorer displays a list of files; folders enable you to 'collapse' groups of files which can make it easier to organize your thoughts or navigate across 'great distances' of many files.  However for navigation there are various other tools (Go To Definition, search for text in the current project, ...) to let you navigate to e.g. a particular class definition.  (Hopefully these tools will continue to improve for F# in particular, as well as VS in general, in future releases.)

In any case, I firmly believe that a "pretty large system of interconnected components (Controller - ViewModel - View, > 300 classes)" is a code smell.  If you can't untangle these to have an archetectural layering such that there are portions that do not depend on other portions (and thus could be defined 'first' in a prior file in F#), then you have bigger problems than just "how to organize your F# code".  My opinionated view is perhaps best-expressed [here](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/13172/ShowThread.aspx#13172).

EDIT (2018): meanwhile, the tools have improved, among many other things, go-to-definition, find-all-references, global renaming of identifiers, folder support, file reorganization etc have been added in the past few years. For solutions that require mutual references between classes, `namespace rec` and `module rec` have been introduced to limit the need for `type ... and ...`.

Comment: Nice post at link! Yeah, the original system is far from layered and this gives me hard time porting it to F#!

Comment: This linear ordering of dependencies is one of the main reasons I will no longer use C# for non-trivial projects (I don't use it for trivial projects for other reasons). F# effectively prevents this (very expensive) mistake I made so frequently in C#. It took some time to appreciate it, and therefore bear with the additional work required, but it's priceless as software grows.

Comment: @Daniel This sounds interesting, but I'm not really following. Could you please elaborate on what "linear ordering of dependecies" means?

Comment: A source file can only depend on other files that appear before it in the project/compilation order.

Answer (score 5):

You can have [folders in F# projects](https://web.archive.org/web/20120116085906/http://cultivatingcode.com/2010/02/12/folders-in-f-projects/), too. It's a bit cumbersome, but it works.

I think putting multiple classes into one file is perfectly okay and idiomatic in F# **if** the classes are closely related to each other.

I have not yet worked with really large F# projects, but I'm also interested in the experience of others.

Comment: @MEMMark: Thanks. Fixed it by linking to archive.org.

Comment: Meanwhile folders are supported out-of-the-box (from VS2017 15.3, I believe).