# Does F# support interdependent classes in separate files?

Tags: f#, circular-dependency

I'm working on IronJS, and one of our source files is getting very long.

Right now, I'm trying to get .NET interop working.  I'm adding the `TryBinaryOperation` method to the `Undefined` so that C# can use the JavaScript semantics of the Undefined value.

However, this introduces a dependency on the `Operators` type, which causes a circular dependency.

Runtime.fs:

```
type BoxedValue() =
    struct
        // Contains IsUndefined and get_Undefined, referencing the Undefined class, below.

...

and type Undefined() =
    inherit DynamicObject()
    ...
    override x.TryBinaryOperation(binder:BinaryOperationBinder, arg:obj, result:obj byref) : bool =
        // Here, we are referencing BoxedValue, above.
        result <- Operators.add(Und, BoxedValue.Box(arg))
        true

...
```

Operators.fs:

```
type Operators =
    ...
    // Here, we are referencing BoxedValue.
    static member add(BoxedValue l, BoxedValue r)
        ...
```

So, we have this set of dependencies:
[image: BoxedValue->Undefined, Undefined->BoxedValue, Undefined->Operators, Operators->BoxedValue]

**Ideally, we would like to split each of these into its own file.**

**Is it possible in F# to have cross-file circular dependencies?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with cyclic dependencies between types and functions from different files in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404735/problem-with-cyclic-dependencies-between-types-and-functions-from-different-files)

Comment: The answer is "no": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404735/problem-with-cyclic-dependencies-between-types-and-functions-from-different-files/5406492#5406492, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396465/how-to-organize-f-source-of-large-project-300-classes-in-visual-studio/5396824#5396824

Comment: It appears someone finally got desperate enough to provide some sort of assistance to this issue: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=snuup.FSharpFileStructure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way to write circular dependencies between types defined in separate files (in the current version of F#). In general, the way to solve the problem is to break one of the dependencies and allow some form of parameterization. Then you can fill the hole to build the circular reference later.

In your example, you can probably reasonably easily parameterize the `Undefined` type to take the reference to `Operators` as a parameter. If you need more functions, then you can use an interface. For just a single function (like `Operators.add`) you can write something like this:

```
and type Undefined() =
    inherit DynamicObject()
    ...
    // To be specified by code defined later 
    // (this can either be a function or an interface implementation)
    static let mutable addition = (fun x y -> failwith "not initialized")
    static member SetAddition(f) = addition <- f

    override x.TryBinaryOperation
            (binder:BinaryOperationBinder, arg:obj, result:obj byref) : bool =
        // Here, we are referencing BoxedValue, above.
        result <- addition(Und, BoxedValue.Box(arg))
        true
```

The code in `Operators.fs` would provide the implementation:

```
type Operators =
    ...
    // Static constructor of the `Operators` type
    static do Undefined.SetAddition(Operators.add)
    ....

    // Here, we are referencing BoxedValue.
    static member add(BoxedValue l, BoxedValue r)
```

The only tricky thing is that you need to make sure that the static constructor of `Operators` will get called before the `Undefined` type is used for the first time. This depends on your specific case, but there is usually some way to do that. (There is probably some main type that can run the initialization)

Comment: Ok, so I've found the one and only one thing that I hate about F#.  But, I hate it so much, I will never use it for anything this big again.

Comment: @John - The F# team listens to feedback, so you may want to send them a note (e.g. at `fsbugs` at `microsoft.com`, which is mainly for bugs, but will work for feedback too). I agree this is a problem - it doesn't come up too often if the code is written in more functional style (e.g. F# compiler is really huge and has no troubles with this).