# Cyclic dependency between functions in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, cyclic-dependency

I am trying break this cyclic dependency below but not sure the best way to do it.

```
let cashOpeningBalance t =
if t = 1 then
    0.0
else
    cashClosingBalance (t - 1)

let cashInterest t = 
    cashOpeningBalance t * 0.03 

let accumulatedCash t =
    cashOpeningBalance t + cashInterest t

// let moreComplicatedLogic t = ...

let cashClosingBalance t =
    accumulatedCash t
```

Using some logic from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404735/problem-with-cyclic-dependencies-between-types-and-functions-from-different-file) I came up with the following solution but the performance is really poor.

```
let cashOpeningBalance t cashClosingBalance =
if t = 1 then
    10.0
else
    cashClosingBalance (t - 1)

let cashInterest t cashClosingBalance = 
    (cashOpeningBalance t cashClosingBalance) * 0.03 

let accumulatedCash t cashClosingBalance =
    (cashOpeningBalance t cashClosingBalance) + (cashInterest t cashClosingBalance)

// let moreComplicatedLogic t cashClosingBalance = ...

let rec cashClosingBalance t =
    //accumulatedCash t cashClosingBalance
    let temp = accumulatedCash t cashClosingBalance
    printfn "Cash Closing Balance = %f Where t = %i" temp t
    temp

cashClosingBalance 3
(*
> 
Cash Closing Balance = 10.300000 Where t = 1
Cash Closing Balance = 10.300000 Where t = 1
Cash Closing Balance = 10.609000 Where t = 2
Cash Closing Balance = 10.300000 Where t = 1
Cash Closing Balance = 10.300000 Where t = 1
Cash Closing Balance = 10.609000 Where t = 2
Cash Closing Balance = 10.927270 Where t = 3
val it : float = 10.92727
*)

cashClosingBalance 50
(*
Takes a really long time 
*)
```

Is there anyway to rewrite the cashClosingBalance function to stop the excessive recursive calls as seen in the output below? I really need to be able to put in a value of t of up to 400 and it still run in seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't really in the fact that you have `moreComplicatedLogic` in the middle (and so it is inconvenient to write big `let rec`). The problem is that your code is implementing [Dynamic Programming algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in an inefficient way.

The recursive calls end up calling `cashClosingBalance` multiple times with the same argument (rather than calling it just once and storing the result in some local cache). In functional programming you can solve this using a fairly general concept of *memoization* but you might be able to rewrite your algorithm differently to make it more efficient.

If you want to use memoization, then you need something like this - the following helper takes a function and creates a function of the same type which caches the results of previous calls:

```
let memoize f = 
  let dict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_, _>() 
  fun v ->
    match dict.TryGetValue(v) with
    | true, res -> res
    | _ -> 
        let res = f v 
        dict.Add(v, res)
        res
```

Then you can rewrite your code using `memoize` like this (I simply wrapped all function definitions in `memoize` and changed the order of arguments so that `t` is the last one):

```
let cashOpeningBalance cashClosingBalance = memoize (fun t ->
  if t = 1 then
    10.0
  else
    cashClosingBalance (t - 1))

let cashInterest cashClosingBalance = memoize (fun t -> 
    (cashOpeningBalance cashClosingBalance t) * 0.03 )

let accumulatedCash cashClosingBalance = memoize (fun t ->
    (cashOpeningBalance cashClosingBalance t) + (cashInterest cashClosingBalance t))

// let moreComplicatedLogic t cashClosingBalance = ...

let rec cashClosingBalance = memoize (fun t -> 
    //accumulatedCash t cashClosingBalance
    let temp = accumulatedCash cashClosingBalance t
    printfn "Cash Closing Balance = %f Where t = %i" temp t
    temp)
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. I like how the memoize function doesn't change the underlying structure of the program!

Comment: Haven't seen this design strategy before. It seems like an ingenious way of dynamically creating a lookup table. *Added to toolbox*