# VS F# canopy test adding folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#, web-testing

I want to ask you, if it´s somehow possible, to add folder, to sort out Test´s a little bit.. When i am doing in C# parts, there is normally option

> right click-> add ->new folder

In F# case, it looks like it´s missing.

I tried to add it even out of VS, via the Win. explorer, but its not working.

[image: adding folder F#]

Edit: I have found quite poor solution and that´s actually, that you create new folder in C# part and then cut it out and paste to F# section but it´s a bit weird, so any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not implemented in VS2013 but you can use F# Power Tools extension (http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/) or create it manually (http://marcinjuraszek.com/2014/03/folders-in-f-projects-how-to-do-it-what-to-avoid.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [F# Project Extender](http://fsprojectextender.codeplex.com/) or edit the project file manually. Details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396636/1773451).

Edit: [This article](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/) explains how to keep your project organized without folders.